# C# - Get values from JSON response and assign them to variables

Tags: c#, json

I have written these lines of code which make an API request and in return I get valid JSON response:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseAddress);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_apiUrl);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ExpandoObject>();
                    return Json(data);
                }

            }
```

The `data` looks like below:

[image]

Is it possible to get the value of `ProductID` and `Price`. I want to assign them to something like:

```
int productId = ...
int price = ...
```

How can i do this using `C#`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sorry to answer to my own question but I just found the solution and i wanted to post here:
You need to add these lines of code after `data`

```
var _dataResponse = JToken.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
var _dataResponseProductID = _dataResponse["ProductID"];
var _dataResponsePrice = _dataResponse["Price"];
```

After that the values taken can be converted to desired `data types.`

Answer (score 4):

.Net 4.0 supports creating dynamic objects directly from json:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>("{ \"productId\":\"124889\" }");
string test= item["productId"];
```

If your using `Json.NET` or `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` - this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object/9326146#9326146) should help you.

Json.Net

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ 'Name': 'Jon Smith', 'Address': { 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY' }, 'Age': 42 }");

string name = stuff.Name;
string address = stuff.Address.City;
```

Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

```
dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse("{ 'Name': 'Jon Smith', 'Address': { 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY' }, 'Age': 42 }");

string name = stuff.Name;
string address = stuff.Address.City;

string name = stuff.Name;
string address = stuff.Address.City;
```

Comment: I have to use it this way: var data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ExpandoObject>();

Comment: `dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(data)`

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Newtonsoft Json nuget package.  Basically, you create an model with the variables you need, then you call the deserialize method from Newtonsoft.  Here's some pseudo code

```
public class MyObject
{ 
    int ProductID { get; set; }
    int Price { get; set; }
    int Systems { get; set; }    
}
```

Then in your method:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MyMethod(string json)
{
     MyObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
}
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Create an object and Deserialize the json object.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert.htm